# Fluentd Parsing error with JSON and Non JSON ending logs

Tags: fluentd

I have a log file where the consecutive lines are coming in different format. one is with JSON object at the end, other is without JSON

**Type 1:**
2020-01-29 09:38:09 [/] [main] INFO  org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer |  |   Tomcat started on port(s): 9021 (http) with context path '/service'

**Type 2:** (With Json in the end)
*2020-01-29 09:38:09 [/] [main] INFO  org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer |  |   Tomcat started on port(s): 9021 (http) with context path '/service' {'key':'value'}*

Using the below code in my fluentd.conf to parse the log file

> @type tail path /root/logs/my-service.log pos_file
>   /root/logs/my-service.log.pos tag my-service.log  @type
>   multiline format_firstline /^\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}/ format1
>   /^(?\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}
>   \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})\s+[(?\w*?(?=/))/(?[^\s]*)]\s+[(?[^\s]+)]\s+(?[^\s]+)\s+(?.+?(?=[?{)|.*)(?.*)/

This format works for the TYPE 2 log format mentioned above, but throwing error with TYPE 1.
As belwo

## 0 dump an error event: error_class=ArgumentError error="params does not exist"

Since JSON is not available at the end.

How do I handle such scenario, this would be really helpful to fix some ongoing issue in my EFK stack.